# Clang warning, -Wimplicit-fallthrough, not triggering for most of my files in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang

When I add this warning under "Other C Flags" in xcodeproj file and build, the warning will only trigger in one of my files. I suspect it is because it is an Objective-C++ file, and the other ones I've tried to trigger this warning in are not. I added -Weverything to "Other C Flags" and it causes lots of warnings to pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Clang 3.9 documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#fallthrough-clang-fallthrough), Clang supports this flag only for C++11 and not C and henve only Obj-C++ and not Obj-C.